# Short story where the Devil goes to a Physics professor for help?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read in an anthology 3-4 years ago. But I get the feeling it was much older than that.

In the story, the Devil in the form of a shy young man comes to meet a Physics professor. He is asking for help in dealing with some kind of inter-dimensional invaders. There is some indication that the Devil is also Prometheus from Greek mythology, the one who gave fire to humans, hence the name Lucifer (Light bringer).

Comment: How did it end?

Comment: I remember it being similar to Asimov's "The Gods themselves". In that they find a third universe along the scale(Original universe of the invaders -> Hell -> Earth -> X) and pass along the invaders there.

Comment: New Twilight Zone, Season 1, Episode 12, Aired 1985.

Comment: I remember a new Twilight Zone episode from 1985, where a math professor accidentally summons a demon and his soul is forfeit unless he can find a loophole.  http://www.steveandmarta.com/i%20of%20newton/ntz_newton_synopsis.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

["The Devil You Don't"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62862) by [Keith Laumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer).

**In the story, the Devil in the form of a shy young man comes to meet a Physics professor. He is asking for help in dealing with some kind of inter-dimensional invaders.**

> "Mr. Lucifer came to fix the lights," Curlene said.
> "Ah—not really," the young man said quickly. "Actually, I came to, er, ask for help, Professor. Your help."
> "Oh, really?" Dimpleby seated himself and stirred sugar into Curlene's cup and took a noisy sip. "Well, how can I be of service?"
> "But first, before I impose on you any further, I need to be sure you understand that I really *am* Lucifer. I mean I don't want to get by on false pretenses." He looked at Curlene anxiously. "I would have told you I wasn't really an electrician, er, Mrs.—"
> "Just call me Curl. Sure you would have."
> "If you say your name's Lucifer, why should I doubt it?" Dimpleby asked with a smile.
> "Well, the point is—I'm *the* Lucifer. You know. The, er, the Devil."
> Dimpleby raised his eyebrows. Curlene made a sound of distressed sympathy.

[. . . .]

> "Stated in its simplest terms," Lucifer said, "the, ah, plane of existence I usually occupy—"
> "Hell, you mean," Curl supplied.
> "Well, that's another of those loaded terms. It really isn't a bad place at all, you know—"
> "But what about it?" Dimpleby prompted. "What about Hell?"
> "It's about to be invaded," Lucifer said solemnly. "By alien demons from another world."

[. . . .]

> "But why come to *me*?" Dimpleby said, eyeing Lucifer through the sudsy glass bottom of his ale mug. "I don't know any spells for exorcising demons."
> "Professor, I'm out of my depth," Lucifer said earnestly. "The old reliable eye of newt and wart of toad recipes don't faze these alien imps for a moment. Now, I admit, I haven't kept in touch with new developments in science as I should have. But *you* have, Professor; you're one of the world's foremost authorities on wave mechanics and Planck's law, and all that sort of thing. If anybody can deal with these chaps, *you* can!"

**There is some indication that the Devil is also Prometheus from Greek mythology, the one who gave fire to humans, hence the name Lucifer (Light bringer).**

> "Mr. Lucifer," Curlene asked, "I hope I'm not being nosy—but how did you get the scar on your side that I saw when you had your shirt off?"
> "Oh, ah, that?" Lucifer blushed purple. "Well, it, ah—"
> "Probably a liver operation, judging from the location, eh, Lucifer?" Dimpleby said.
> "You might call it that," Lucifer said.
> "But you shouldn't embarrass people by asking personal questions, Curl," Dimpleby said sternly.
> "Yes, dear," Curl said. "Lucifer—I've been wanting to ask you: What did a nice fellow like you do to get kicked out of Heaven?"
> "Well, I uh," Lucifer swallowed.
> "It was for doing something nice, wasn't it?"
> "Well—frankly, I thought it wasn't fair," Lucifer blurted. "I felt sorry for the poor humans, squatting in those damp caves . . ."
> "So you brought them fire," Curlene said. "That's why you're called Lucifer."
> "You're mixed up, Curl," Dimpleby said. "That was Prometheus. For his pains, he was chained to a rock, and every day a vulture tore out his liver, and every night it grew back . . ."
> "But it left a scar," Curlene said, looking meltingly at Lucifer.